# aio_write takes more time than plain write on ext4?

Tags: c

I have a C program that writes 32768 blocks, each block is 16K size (total size of 512MB), to an ext4 filesystem on a system running 3.18.1 kernel. The regular write system call version of this program takes 5.35 seconds to finish the writes (as measured by gettimeofday before and after the for loop). The async io version of this program however takes the following times:

1. to queue all the aio_writes (32768 aio_writes): 7.43 seconds
2. poll to finish each IO request: additional 4.93 seconds

The output files are opened with these flags:O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, O_NONBLOCK

Why does async io take more than double the write() time? Even the Time-to-queue-async-io-request/time-to-write-sync-io is 1.4.

Since some people marked it off-topic, I looked at the definition and decided to paste the code - that seems to be the only reason why it should be marked off-topic. I am not asking why the code is not working, only why aio is much slower than regular writes, especially since all parallel writes are to different blocks. Here's the aio code, followed by the non-aio code:

#### AIO program

```
#define MAX_AIO        (16384*2)
#define BUFSIZE        16384

struct mys {
    int status;
    struct aiocb aio;
};

void set_aiocb(struct mys *aio, int num, int fd)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        aio[i].aio.aio_fildes = fd;
        aio[i].aio.aio_offset = BUFSIZE * i;
        aio[i].aio.aio_buf = malloc(BUFSIZE);
        set_buf(aio[i].aio.aio_buf, BUFSIZE, i);
        aio[i].aio.aio_nbytes = BUFSIZE;
        aio[i].aio.aio_reqprio = fd;
        aio[i].aio.aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_NONE;
        aio[i].aio.aio_sigevent.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;
        aio[i].aio.aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &aio[i];
        aio[i].aio.aio_lio_opcode = 0;
        aio[i].status = EINPROGRESS;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int fd = open("/tmp/AIO", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    int i, open_reqs = MAX_AIO;
    struct mys aio[MAX_AIO];
    struct timeval start, end, diff;

    set_aiocb(aio, MAX_AIO, fd);

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_AIO; i++)
        aio_write(&aio[i].aio);

    while (open_reqs > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_AIO; i++) {
            if (aio[i].status == EINPROGRESS) {
                aio[i].status = aio_error(&(aio[i].aio));
                if (aio[i].status != EINPROGRESS)
                    open_reqs--;
            }
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    timersub(&end, &start, &diff);
    printf("%d.%d\n", (int)diff.tv_sec, (int)diff.tv_usec);
}
```

#### Regular IO program

```
#define MAX_AIO        (16384*2)
#define BUFSIZE        16384

char buf[MAX_AIO][BUFSIZE];
void main(void)
{
    int i, fd = open("/tmp/NON_AIO", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
    struct timeval start, end, diff;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_AIO; i++)
        write(fd, buf[i], BUFSIZE);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    timersub(&end, &start, &diff);
    printf("%d.%d\n", (int)diff.tv_sec, (int)diff.tv_usec);
}
```

Comment: Using lio_listio() instead makes aio as performant as sync io. But no improvement.

Comment: Note that on Unix systems, `void main()` is an error.  If you're on Linux and GCC didn't complain, you aren't using enough warning options on your compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really comparing apples with apples.

In the AIO code, you have a separately allocated buffer for each of the write operations, so the program has 512 MiB (16 * 16 * 2 KiB) of memory allocated, plus the 32 K copies of the AIO control structure.  That memory has to be allocated, initialized (each buffer gets a different value if the `set_buf()` function — which is not shown — sets each byte of the buffer to the value of the third parameter), then copied by the kernel to the driver, possibly via the kernel buffer pool.

In the regular IO code, you have one big, contiguous buffer which is initialized to all zeroes which you write to the disk.

To make the comparison equitable, you should use the same infrastructure in both programs, creating the AIO structures, but the regular IO code will then simply step through the structures, writing the data portion of each (while the AIO code will behave more or less as shown).  And I expect you will find that the performance is a lot more nearly similar when you do that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your response till today. How does this explanation explain the 2x drop? The buffers are allocated before the timing is started, including the set_buf (which allocates the buffer and sets the data to a pattern). I am setting the pattern in the regular non aio code too, didnt put it as I wanted to show the comparison part only.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't explain it — but it does emphasize that you have to be excruciatingly careful when benchmarking.  My best guess is that with the AIO in use, the kernel ends up driving the disk heads all over the place, which is slow, whereas with the regular IO (SIO, for synchronous I/O?), the kernel ends up smoothing out the access patterns.  But I'm not sure.  I think that what you show does have some apples vs oranges issues, but maybe the 'real code' doesn't have the issues as badly.

Comment: The other part of problem may be that you are throwing 32K AIO requests at the system, and it has allocate storage etc for handling those requests.  I've not looked at the implementation in the kernel; I don't know how much allocation it has to do for each AIO request, but it probably isn't nothing and 32K AIO requests could be swamping the system.  Have you tried splitting the AIO into 32 groups of 1K AIO requests, or even 1K groups of 32 AIO requests, to see how long that takes?